# Using Linq to select a List<object> and casting it to List<string>

Tags: c#, linq, casting

The method i'm calling accepts `List<string>`. 
I need to select what i want from a List

```
listviewItems.Select(x => x.Tag).ToList()
```

But since the Tag itself is an object it won't work because the result is `List<object>`. 
I've also tried

```
listviewItems.Select(x => (string) x.Tag).ToList()

(List<string>) listviewItems.Select(x => x.Tag).ToList()

listviewItems.Select(x => (List<string>) x.Tag).ToList()
```

but none of these return a `List<string>`. 
What is the correct way to cast this?

Comment: Do you know what are they returning?

Comment: `listviewItems.Select(x => (string) x.Tag).ToList()` returns `List<string>`

Comment: @user3185569 ... or an error, perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does return a `List<string>`. There's a problem somewhere else in your code.

```
listviewItems.Select(x => (string) x.Tag).ToList()
```

Comment: This is the first one i tried: Error 6 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: Never mind i'm dumb, the error was marking the second argument as wrong where it's also expecting a List<string>.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call .ToString() on the objects. However, it will depend on whether or not you're calling from the database.

In memory option:

```
listviewItems.Select(x => x.Tag?.ToString() ?? "").ToList()
```

From Entity Framework:

```
listviewItems.Select(x => x.Tag)
             .ToList() // Get them in memory first as the ToString doesn't convert to SQL.
             .Select(tag => tag.ToString()) // Then convert to string
             .ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think you can even have an `object` type property on an entity, therefore I don't see how EF is related.

Comment: Of course you can. It's a related object. That's how Foreign Keys work. But if you're pulling them out of your Context, and just do a `Select(x => x.Tag)`, it will ignore the main object, and just retrieve the Tag object for that main object. The problem is that if you to `.ToString()` within the database call, it will try to convert that to SQL, and fail.

Comment: What I mean is he apparently has a `public object Tag { get; set; }` - AFAIK that is not something you can do in EF.

Comment: Gotcha. I was aiming for a generic answer that will help future visitors as well. The `listviewItems` name pointed me to the fact that it probably wasn't an EF call.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a `List<Object>` you could use [`List.ConvertAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<string> strings = objects.ConvertAll(obj => obj?.ToString());
```

If you are going to build it you should convert the objects to strings in the first place:

```
List<string> strings = listviewItems.Select(x => x.Tag?.ToString()).ToList();
```